# Change Exchange Server Name Before Upgrade

Tags: exchange, outlook

I need to upgrade the Exchange Server from 2003 to 2010.  I'm physically changing servers as well as software.  I'm worried about redirecting the Outlook clients after the upgrade is going to be troublesome.  So, I thought that before doing anything else, that I would change the name of the Exchange server on the client from 'server-name.domain.com' to 'mail.domain.com' and add an entry in dns that points 'mail.domain.com' to the same ip as 'server-name.domain.com'.  However, even though I added 'mail.domain.com' to the dns, I cannot get the Exchange server to change to that on the client computers.  I found out that the Outlook clients check the Global Catalog for the name of the Exchange server computer.

My question is: can I change the Global Catalog address of the Exchange computer from 'server-name.domain.com' to 'mail.domain.com'?  If so/not, is there a better way to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set them up on separate names. When you move the mailboxes from the 2003 server to the 2010 server, Outlook will update its own configuration with the correct details, and the user will be asked to restart their copy of Outlook if it's running when the change happens.

I would of course stongly suggest you try it out in a lab, or on one users account first, before doing all the migrations.